# $\arctan \left(\frac{\sin x}{1+\cos x}\right)$

Tags: trigonometry

I see on Desmos that

$$\arctan \left(\frac{\sin x}{1+\cos x}\right)$$

is just half $x$ between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$.

How can I know this without plotting it?

Comment: Be familiar with half-angle formulas. You don't need to remember this specific one, just recognize from now one that $\displaystyle\frac{a}{1\pm b}$ (with $a,b$ two complementary functions) and their reciprocals represent half-angle formulas.

Comment: You don't need the half-angle formulas, but the double-angle ones.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Why would someone use the double angle formulas on $\sin x$ and $\cos x$, though, if they didn't already know the final answer involved $\frac{x}{2}$?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I did, that's why I posted my comment.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Correct, I did see that. And?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\frac{\sin x}{1+\cos x}=\frac{2\sin \dfrac x2\cos \dfrac x2}{2\cos^2\dfrac x2}=\tan \dfrac x2.$$